# SFMC Receiving dedicated IPAddress information from _JOB per JobID

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, job, jobid

I'm trying to create a report to retrieve IPAddress from _Job table per each JobID using query but i comes back as NULL. According to SFMC information IPAddress is only available to users without dedicated IP addresses assigned which doesn't really make logical sense to me... Is there any other way I can create a report to see what IP addresses are used for each Job ID?
Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. I've had a look and it appears that you can't retrieve Delivery Profile details (e.g. IP address) from standard data views. I would suggest opening a support case; they should be able to expose this information for you. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @Joseph, have you had any updates on this?

Comment: Sorry, this system is not sending any email notifications... No I was not able to find but I did find custom reports option under email section

Comment: did you get support to expose the variables to you? :)

Comment: I was able to generate a report using SF report builder. Customer support was unuseful...

Comment: Hi @Joseph, with which report did you made it? I have the same issue